# Use "can" with definitions

Tags: modal-verbs

> - Train station: you **can** get a train here.
> - Tourist information office: tourists **can** get information here.
> - Post office: you **can** post letters and parcels here.
>
>   English Vocabulary in Use book

I noticed *can* is used with definitions. Is this common? Can we define the above items without *can*?

> - Train station: you get a train here.
> - Tourist information office: tourists get information here.
> - Post office: you post letters and parcels here.

And why does the writer use *here* not *there*?

Comment: Yes, you can write the definitions without using *can*. *Here* is used to indicate the speaker (writer) is communicating from the point of view of being at the named location. *There* would change the point of view to being at a place other than the named location.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can you not use "can"?

If you want to maintain the meanings of the sentences (which I assume you do), then you should use "can".  By including the word "can", you are saying that the subject IS ABLE to perform the action (but does not necessarily have to).

However, if you remove the word "can", you introduce some ambiguity into the situation.  Without the word "can", you might be saying "Tourists ALWAYS get information here", or you could be saying "Some tourists get information here".  By including the word "can", it makes it very clear-- "Tourists may get information here, but they don't have to."

Bottom line (in my opinion): If some tourists choose to get information and others don't, it is best to use "can".

---

#### Why use *here* instead of *there*?

By using the word *here*, the author suggests that he is standing AT the location spoken of.  In the train station example, the author is standing AT the train station, saying that tourists COME to his current location.  In the post office example, the author is standing AT the post office saying that you can post parcels and letters at his current location.

However, if the author had used *there*, he would be suggesting that he is standing somewhere **other** than the location spoken of.  For example, he might be at his home and say that tourists can go *there* (to the train station) to get information.

~~~

This is off-topic, but the same principle applies to "take" vs. "bring".  Bring is what you use for when something is bring transported to your current location.  Take, on the other hand, is what you use when something is being transported to a location *other* than your current one.